# Technically, How does uploading Apps to an Android Phone Work?

Tags: android, protocol

Amazon.com has an Android Marketplace. How do the apps go from Amazon.com to my phone? I am looking for a **protocol level** analysis. Do they use a basic protocol like FTP and then check with a Google digital signature? I do not own an Android.

I wish for an explanation of how the protocol operates because I want to provide an android app for free download for my users off my website, like Amazon does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost certainly HTTPS.

If you want to offer android apps for download, you can just put the .apk file on your site and link to it.  Mind you, only people who've ticked the option for "Allow unauthorised sources" will be able to download it.

Why don't you just submit it to the Google Play store?